# How to get full path of changes files only using git status in Windows?

Tags: git

Let's say I have changed two files in my project.

My project is located at `C:\Projects\Website`.

When I use `git status --porcelain` I get this result:

```
 M Component.jsx
?? Public/Index.html
```

What I need is to remove initial prefixes of each line, and get the full path of changed files:

```
C:\Projects\Website\Component.jsx
C:\Projects\Website\Public\Index.html
```

I need this, because I'm creating a linter software and I want to get the list of changed files and analyze them statically.

Answer (score 0):

A simple batch file should be able to provide what you want (assuming that I understand the question).

I just whipped this up:

```bat
    @echo off

    for /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%c in ('git status --porcelain') do call :AnalizePaths "%cd%" "%%c"
    goto :EOF

    :: ----------------------------------------------------------
    :: Procedure: AnalizePaths
    :: ----------------------------------------------------------
    :AnalizePaths
    Set BaseDirectory=%~1
    Set ChangedFile=%~2

    Set FullPath=%BaseDirectory%\%ChangedFile%
    Set FullPath=%FullPath:/=\%

    If "%FullPath:~-1%"=="\" echo %FullPath% is a path and not a file &&goto :EOF

    Echo look at changed file "%FullPath%".
    goto :EOF
```